# Why query just returns first 100 users?

Tags: parse-platform

I want get 40 users where "score" less or equal to some value, and 40 users where "score" greater or equal to the same value. But both queries return just first 100 users which sorted by score in descending order.
Here is some part of code

```
var query = ParseUser.Query;

        if(mode==0)
        {
            query.WhereNotEqualTo("fbLogged", true)
                 .WhereNotEqualTo("username", SaveManager.Instance.TempUsername)
                 .WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("score", SaveManager.Instance.Score)
                 .Limit(40);
        }

        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
            {
                foreach (var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                    Debug.LogError("Error: " + e.Message);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var query1 = ParseUser.Query;

                if(mode==0)
                {
                    query1.WhereNotEqualTo("fbLogged", true)
                    .WhereNotEqualTo("username", SaveManager.Instance.TempUsername)
                    .WhereLessThanOrEqualTo("score", SaveManager.Instance.Score)
                    .Limit(40);
                }

                query1.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t1=>
                {
                    Debug.Log("first query count: " + t.Result.ToList().Count);
                    Debug.Log("second query count: " + t1.Result.ToList().Count);

                    var r = t.Result.ToList();
                    r.AddRange(t1.Result.ToList());

                    List<UserRank> ranks = new List<UserRank>();
                    r.ForEach(info => { ranks.Add(RetrieveUserRankData((ParseUser)info)); });

                    ranks = ranks.OrderByDescending(ur => ur.Score).ToList();

                    UserRank first = ranks.First();
                    UserRank last = ranks.Last();

                    Debug.Log("my score: " + SaveManager.Instance.Score);
                    Debug.Log("first name and score: " + first.Name + " " + first.Score);
                    Debug.Log("last name and score: " + last.Name + " " + last.Score);
```

Also here is the log

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a query default limit is 100 rows. And the maximum number of rows is 1000. To increase the limit, use `query.setLimit(1000)` to increase the number of queried row to 1000.

Comment: Actually I use Limit(40), not 101 or 200, LIMIT(40), 40! 40<100, but it returns 100.